# C++ STL map with a custom class as second type

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'd like to create a map with an int and my own custom class.  Is there a way to do this?

```
map<int, MyClass> myMap;
```

If not, how do I go about accomplishing this?  Basically, I want an id(or preferably an `enum`) to point to my own custom class.  In most other languages, this would be a simple hash.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
#include <map>

std::map<int, MyClass> myMap;

MyClass foo;
myMap[5] = foo;
myMap[5].bar = 10;
```

You do need `MyClass` to be default- and copy- constructible, so it can be created (if you use, e.g., `myMap[5]`) and copied into the map.

Comment: I think you only need the default constructor if you use operator[].

Comment: Maybe even add "typedef std::map<int, MyClass> MyMapType;"

Comment: while using [] operator with map we should take care if already this key exist, otherwise earlier value will be replaced by new value , which may lead to a crisis

Answer (score 4):

Yes the only condition are:

- The key Type is comparable (Good)
- The value Type is copy constructable ?

So you just need to make sure you are object is copy constructable so that it can be copied into the map.

Comment: Of course you don't even need the copy constructor if only storing pointers to instances of the class in the map instead.

Comment: @Troubadour: Sort of true. But in that case you are storing a pointer. The equivalent of copy constructor for a POD type is simple assignment (so I always equate the two as the same) and this just makes a copy of the pointer. The other side affect of this is the map owns the pointer not the object. The map will release the pointer but not the object it is pointing at (so no delete). For this we have boost::ptr_map<int,MyClass>

Answer (score 0):

you should use like this

typedef std::map myMapType;

myMapType myMap;

But be careful when inserting your class in this as if you insert more than one time for same key, you will never get a notice :

Call myMapType::iterator itr myMap.find(key) , depending upon return type and your program requirments you can procced.

Like wise try to avid access any element using [] operator like

```
 somefunc(myMap[10]);
```

As you will not get an error from map even there was noting inserted for key 10