# 'No matching function for call' error when inserting class into a STL map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, std

I have a STL map in C++ where the key is an unsigned int, and the value is a class whose constructor is:

```
Foo::Foo(unsigned int integerValue){
    //Some stuff
}
```

At other class I have declarated the std::map at the header:

```
private:
    std::map<unsigned int, Foo> *m_mapFoo;
```

And at the cpp file I created it and inserted instances of Foo:

```
m_mapFoo = new std::map<unsigned int, Foo>;
m_mapFoo->insert(0, new Foo(0));
m_mapFoo->insert(1, new Foo(1));
```

But I'm getting the following error at the insert methods:

```
no matching function for call to ‘std::map<unsigned int, Foo, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, Foo> > >::insert(const unsigned int&, Foo*)’
```

Similar problem at find method:

```
m_mapFoo.find(0)->second->someFunctionIntoFooClass();
```

Where the error is exactly the following:

```
request for member ‘find’ in ‘((Foo*)this)->Foo::m_mapGeoDataProcess’, which is of non-class type ‘std::map<unsigned int, Foo, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, Foo> > >*’
```

Additional notes: I don't have a Foo copy constructor, but I don't think that's the problem.

Any help understanding this errors?

Comment: How do you expect to copy into a map if you don't have a copy constructor?

Comment: I have read around stackoverflow and some people say you must have, some say you don't need. But I don't know if that's applicable only to [] insertation and not insert method. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478330/c-stl-map-with-a-custom-class-as-second-type

Comment: You need the copy constructor for `insert`. `emplace` doesn't need it, though.

Comment: @Pubby OP probably has the compiler synthesized copy constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a pointer to a map containing `Foo` values

```
std::map<unsigned int, Foo> *m_mapFoo;
```

and you are treating it as if it contained `Foo` pointer values:

```
std::map<unsigned int, Foo*> *m_mapFoo;
```

Try this:

```
m_mapFoo = new std::map<unsigned int, Foo>;
m_mapFoo->insert(std::make_pair(0, Foo(0)));
m_mapFoo->insert(std::make_pair(1, Foo(1)));
```

As for the second error, you have a pointer to a map, so you need

```
std::map<unsigned int, Foo>::iterator it = m_mapFoo->find(0);
if (it) {
  it->second.someFunctionIntoFooClass();
} else {
  // entry not found
}
```

Comment: That seems to work, thanks! But still having the second error at find method. Any idea?

Comment: @RomanRdgz I added something about the second error. Beware that you should check the result of `std::map::find`.

Comment: the error remains, the same: request for member find... I also have included <algorithm> with same results (I had forgotten)

Comment: @RomanRdgz sorry, I had made a typo in the line where I use `std::map::find` and call teh `Foo` function. It should work now.

Answer (score 3):

Your map is typed to store **objects** of type `Foo`, not **pointers** to objects of type `Foo`. Seeing as you're trying to initialise the elements with `new` and access their members via `->`, you probably want:

```
private:
    std::map<unsigned int, Foo*> *m_mapFoo;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the little information you give, it seems unlikely that you need to use pointers *anywhere*:  Try this:

In the header:

```
private:
    std::map<unsigned int, Foo> m_mapFoo;
```

And at the cpp file:

```
m_mapFoo[0] = Foo(0);
m_mapFoo[1] = Foo(1);
```

The semantics of `operator[]` are slightly different than `.insert()`. If you need `.insert()`, use it. But unless you are relying upon the subtle difference, use the more readable `operator[]`.

Similarly at the find method, the expression becomes much more readable if you avoid pointers and use `operator[]`:

```
m_mapFoo[0].someFunctionIntoFooClass();
```