# What happens when adding custom type objects to std::map?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I had trouble adding the `foo` object into the map `myFoos` until I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478330/c-stl-map-with-a-custom-class-as-second-type) which states that a default constructor is required.

When adding the object to the map, I was expecting it to be simply copied and put in place, however, what really happens is a default construction, an assignment and a copy.

Can someone explain this behaviour?

```
#include <map>

using namespace::std;

class Foo {
public:
  Foo() { }; // Default
  Foo(int id) : _id(id) { }; // Main
  Foo(const Foo& other) { }; // Copy
  Foo operator= (const Foo& other) { _id = other._id; return *this; } // Assign
  int getID() { return _id; }
private:
  int _id;
};

int main()
{
  map<int,Foo> myFoos;
  Foo foo(123);      // Main
  myFoos[123] = foo; // Default, Assign, Copy
}
```

**Edit:** 
I originally had no assignment happening in the function body of the assignment operator and some answers are correctly pointing that out. I modified the code accordingly.

Comment: It will be in any documentation you find for `operator[]`.

Comment: You've forgotten to do anything inside your `= operator` code. Set the id from the id of other at a minimum,or better yet, use the `copy and swap` idiom, as detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before any assignments and copies can be done, the code `myFoos[123]` needs to create a `Foo` to insert into the map for the key `123`. That value is then copied or moved into the `map` and then returned to you for further manipulation.

The index operator returns a reference to the element in the map, if it doesn't exist, it creates it and inserts it for you. If it does already exist, it just returns a reference to that already pre-existent one.

See [`std::map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at).

> `T& operator[]( Key&& key );`
>
> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to `key`, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.
>
> If an insertion is performed, the mapped value is value-initialized (default-constructed for class types, zero-initialized otherwise) and a reference to it is returned.

---

> `int id = myFoos[123].getID(); // returns 0 instead of 123`

The `0` here is because the class is not yet fully implemented (default and copy constructor, and assignment operator), so the `id` is as initialised in the default constructor (in this case 0).

Answer (score 3):

`operator[]` initializes the element for the specified key using the default constructor, and returns a reference to it.

Your assignment operator omits (intentionally or otherwise) the assignment

`_id = other._id`.

Thus, in

`myFoos[123] = foo;`

the default `_id=0` is not replaced by `foo._id`.

Comment: I see. I defined the assignment operator in order to see when it gets called (I had it write it out) and so I messed up the actual assignment. My bad. Thank you for pointing it out.